# fit image asset in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I'm trying to fit the image with my CircleAvatar, I've tried setting the height and width of the image but it didn't work. Tried BoxFit.fill, BoxFit.cover, BoxFit.fitWidth and BoxFit.fitHeight but still didn't work.

Here is the CircleAvatar:

[image]

And my code:

```
  ClipOval(
    child: conversation.image=='' ? 
           CircleAvatar(child: Image.asset('assets/images/defaultuser.png',),radius: 25,) : 
           CircleAvatar(child: Image.network(conversation.image!),radius: 25,)
    ),
```

Any solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `backgroundImage` instead of `child` property of `CircleAvatar`.

```
class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final networkImage =
      'https://images.pexels.com/photos/462118/pexels-photo-462118.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500';
  final assetImage = 'assets/images/defaultuser.png';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: CircleAvatar(
        radius: 25.0,
        backgroundImage: networkImage.isEmpty
            ? AssetImage(assetImage)
            : NetworkImage(networkImage) as ImageProvider,
        child: const SizedBox.shrink(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: @thecodexhub why here typecasted as ImageProvider?

Comment: @nagendranag If not typecasted, there will be an error that says `The argument type 'Object' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'ImageProvider<Object>?'`. There is an issue on flutter sdk regarding this, check [here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/77782).

Comment: @thecodexhub Nice.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap `ClipOval` with `Sizebox` so that always it have same size and height

```
                   SizedBox(
                            height: 60,
                            width: 60,
                            child: ClipOval(
                                    child: conversation.image=='' ? 
           Image.asset('assets/images/defaultuser.png',fit:BoxFit.cover,):
           Image.network(conversation.image!,fit:BoxFit.cover,),))
```

This should generate image like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/uxq4c.png

Comment: Tried this but still didn't work @Saddan

Comment: You have another issue I guess. I added a sample image which is a result of my code you may check.You also need to update code and add the clip oval container also

Answer (score 0):

```
ClipOval(
                                  child: CachedNetworkImage(
                                    width: 100.0,
                                    height: 100.0,
                                    fit: BoxFit.cover,
                                    imageUrl: "",
                                    placeholder: (context, url) =>
                                        new CircularProgressIndicator(),
                                    errorWidget: (context, url, error) =>
                                        new Icon(
                                      Icons.account_circle,
                                      color: Colors.blue,
                                      size: 100,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
```

Answer (score 0):

**Use "*backgroundImage*" property instead of "*child*" property of CircleAvatar**

```
ClipOval(
   child: conversation.image=='' ?
   CircleAvatar(
     backgroundImage: AssetImage('assets/images/defaultuser.png',),radius: 25):
   CircleAvatar(
     backgroundImage: NetworkImage(conversation.image!),radius: 25)),
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your image is rectangular that's why it doesn't fit in `CircleAvatar`.

Try this

```
 CircleAvatar(
          backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
          child: ClipOval(
            clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
            child: ImageAssetWidget(
              imagePath: ImageAssets.cardHomeTopBG,
            ),
          ),
          radius: 25,
        ),
```